# Django Rest Framework does not filter after resetting queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My url will be something like: ... /? Search = modal.

I want to replace the "modal" with empty "" to clean the filter and return all records.

**Views.py**

```
class AnexoExamesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

search_fields = ['descr']
filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
queryset = AnexoExames.objects.all()
serializer_class = AnexoExamesSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = AnexoExames.objects.all()
    search_descr = self.request.query_params.get('search',None)
    print(search_descr)
    if search_descr=='modal':            
        queryset = AnexoExames.objects.filter(descr='')                
    return queryset
```

This way it is returning zero results

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a django-filter that worked as I needed it to. I prefer this simple solution that you should be able to use to solve your problem:

**views.py**

```py
# inherits APIView, ModelViewSet, etc.
class View(...):

    # override get_queryset method like so:
    def get_queryset(self):
        
        queryset = self.queryset
        custom_filter = self.request.query_params.get('filter')
        
        if custom_filter: 
            custom_filter = json.loads(custom_filter)
            queryset = queryset.filter(**custom_filter)
        
        return queryset
```

Then we can filter from javascript like so:

**script.js**

```js
// create the django-like filter:
var filter = JSON.stringify({
  'modal__name' : 'My Modal Name',
})

var url = '.../api/test?filter=' + filter;
```

Your url will look like: `.../api/test?filter={"modal__name":"My Modal Name"}`